# How do I access the columns of this table?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my variable, tv.table, printed:

```
> tv.table
 sex.permuted
        B   G
  d    87  94
  dvm  49  52
  l   249 277
  lvm 197 193
  n   143 139
```

I would like to access just the columns of tv.table.  Usually, I would do this with the commands tv.table$B and tv.table$G.  However, this is not working, I suspect because of the column header above B and G labeled sex.permuted.  How do I get rid of that?

Comment: If you want help from people on the internet about R, you'll have to learn how to best provide the information necessary to answer your question. How your data appears when printed on the screen is almost always useless. Use tools like `?str` and `?dput` to share the exact structure of your objects.

Comment: Is `tv.table` the result of a call to `table`?  That might be important to note in the post.  You can probably do `tv.table[,"B"]`, or some variation of depending on the deparse level.

Comment: Is `tv.table` a list?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an R table object. It has dimensions that have a dimname and then columnnames and rownames. Since they are really matrices, the access method is via the "[" function:

```
> with(airquality,
+    table(OzHi = Ozone > 80, Month, useNA = "ifany"))
       Month
OzHi     5  6  7  8  9
  FALSE 25  9 20 19 27
  TRUE   1  0  6  7  2
  <NA>   5 21  5  5  1
> attributes( with(airquality,
+    table(OzHi = Ozone > 80, Month, useNA = "ifany")) )
$dim
[1] 3 5

$dimnames
$dimnames$OzHi
[1] "FALSE" "TRUE"  NA     

$dimnames$Month
[1] "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"


$class
[1] "table"
```

So to access the first and second columns refer t them by their character names:

```
> airtbl <-  with(airquality,
+    table(OzHi = Ozone > 80, Month, useNA = "ifany"))

> airtbl[ , c("5","6")]
       Month
OzHi     5  6
  FALSE 25  9
  TRUE   1  0
  <NA>   5 21
```